# Laravel 4: Cannot send email with inline embedding

Tags: email, laravel-4, embed

Need help: how to send emails with inline image?

The response returns 200 OK but email is not being sent. But when I removed $message->embed() everything is alright.

I used {{ $message->embed('img/logo.png') }} in the view file, but the email is not sending, is it wrong location of image? (i have triedputting logo.png in public/img dir and app/views/emails/img dir, my email view file is in app/views/emails/mail.blade.php).Or is it something else?

Answer (score 6):

for Embeding an image try this:

```
<img width="250px" src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('img/logo.png')) }}" alt="logo">
```

remember that folder img must be in public.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `URL::asset('img/logo.png')` instead of the direct path and always put your static files in `public folder`.

Comment: Well it returns soemthing like `https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/eO6iscXeqg6wgPIj8_Svu45XDG8bYW4yZGwZnYOxdy0gqdfr6tqhvZ3m6DTy44OoLMJrKJCQsuY66h2zqz_oOA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost/public/img/logo.png` which gmail can't read, I solved the problem already (apparently i named the folder wrong).Thank you