# Laravel: How to embed image in an email as a content and not as an attachment

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

I have searched for ways to embed an image in an email sent with Laravel. The method I have found which most people use is to embed the image as an attachment.

```
<img src="{{$message->embed(asset('assets/img/logo.png'))}}" style="padding:0px; margin:0px" />
```

Is there a way to embed an image without it being an attachment? I tried converting the image to base64 strings but that didn't even work.

Comment: I don't think it's a very good idea, because support for inline (encoded) images in email clients is sparse. Some allow it some strip the image away (actually I think none of the major web based email clients Gmail, Yahoo, etc. allow this).

Comment: But I do receive emails where images are embedded but not as attachemnts

Comment: @BlackPearl That doesn't mean it works everywhere, nor does it mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: Cannot send email with inline embedding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464413/laravel-4-cannot-send-email-with-inline-embedding)

Answer (score 15):

Whether its a good thing or not...

You nearly have it. I suppose the problem is that the `asset()` function is generating a full url and Laravel need the path to the file. [Official Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail#embedding-inline-attachments)

Try this:

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed('assets/img/logo.png') }}" style="padding:0px; margin:0px" />
```

Comment: won't this embed the file as an attachment?

Comment: @BlackPearl I don't think so. If you take a look at the official docs i linked. It states that its for embedding inline attachments. also, if you scroll up a bit, you see the "normal" method to attach files.

Comment: Which is what exactly? It gets attached as attachment?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe try using the `embedData` function and passing in a base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

You need specify full path so,

```
<img src='{{ $message->embed(public_path().'/img/image.jpg') }}'>
```